# EC2 volume: how do I set it so that it WILL delete on termination?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, volume, termination

I have an EC2 instance that I'd like to take a snapshot of, to use as an AMI for future spot instances.
Because of the way I created volume for this instance, it is currently set to *not* delete upon termination.
I want it *to* delete on termination, so that I can use it for spot instances and not have residual volumes hanging around needing manual deletion.

I've combed AWS manual, stack exchange, google, etc and I can only find references to a 'delete on termination' flag, but no explanation of how to use it.

Comment: I got the answer, but stackoverflow won't let me submit it for a while because I'm too much a newb.  The trick is to use the argumennt  -b "/dev/sda1=::true"  after ec2-request-spot-instances

Comment: The same -b option can be used on ec2-modify-instance-attributes to configure an instance that has already been placed into service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

enable delete on termination, for example
http://itsecureadmin.com/2011/06/aws-instance-ebs-volume-delete-on-termination/

Answer (score 11):

Taking on what @akshar wrote, you can have it all in the same line, without the need for an additional json file:

```
 aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --instance-id i-123abc45 --block-device-mappings "[{\"DeviceName\": \"/dev/sdf\",\"Ebs\":{\"DeleteOnTermination\":true}}]"
```

where `/dev/sdf` is the mount point in your instance

Comment: Excellent answer. Googling on this issue finds surprisingly little documentation as to how to determine or modify this flag.

Comment: This was amazing. I was doing this by getting the attached volume through tagging filter.

Comment: Delete on termination was covered by the chapter [Preserve Amazon EBS volumes on instance termination](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/terminating-instances.html#preserving-volumes-on-termination) of the official EC2 guide. It only offers the choice of CLI as Doron has described, it cannot be done through the console.

Answer (score 2):

Taking on what everybody else said, one line and without JSON encoding and ugly escapes:

```
modify-instance-attribute --instance-id $ID --block-device-mappings 'DeviceName=/dev/sdf,Ebs={DeleteOnTermination=true}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use AWS-CLI to do this:

The simplest way is to use `modify-instance-attribute` subcommand provided by `aws ec2` command.

```
aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --instance-id i-123ab12f --block-device-mappings file://~/some.json
```

Content of file `some.json` should be:

```
[
    {
    "DeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
    "Ebs": {
      "DeleteOnTermination": true
      }
    }
]
```

Shameless Plug: If you regularly work with AWS, take this highly engaging [AWS Quiz](http://awsquiz.net?src=s) to check your AWS knowledge.