# How to enable 'delete on termination' for EBS volumes using Java AWS SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to find setting/method through which we can tell AWS SDK to delete an EBS volume on termination. This setting is available through AWS console but not through AWS Java SDK.

My code to create an EBS volume looks like below

```
CreateVolumeRequest volumeRequest = new CreateVolumeRequest(volumeSize, availabilityZone);
Volume vol = EC2_CLIENT.createVolume(volumeRequest).getVolume();
```

Can anyone please tell me how to enable delete on termination for EBS volume using Java SDK?

Comment: Don't know if it applies to Java, but I notice that boto (for Python) has a deleteOnTermination setting for modify_network_interface_attribute().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you found the solution or workaround by yourself, but I had the same problem and I found this question on Google, so I'll write an answer for future developers.

It seems that enabling delete on termination cannot be done during creating or attaching an EBS, but only via **modify instance attribute** operation.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24586795/2708102) explains how to do this via CLI.
Analogous method for AWS SDK for Java is to change device mapping settings by using [AmazonEC2Client#modifyInstanceAttribute()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2Client.html#modifyInstanceAttribute%28com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.ModifyInstanceAttributeRequest%29)

My code looks like this:

```
EbsInstanceBlockDeviceSpecification ebsSpecification = new EbsInstanceBlockDeviceSpecification()
        .withDeleteOnTermination(true);

InstanceBlockDeviceMappingSpecification mappingSpecification = new InstanceBlockDeviceMappingSpecification()
        .withDeviceName(deviceName)
        .withEbs(ebsSpecification);

ModifyInstanceAttributeRequest request = new ModifyInstanceAttributeRequest()
        .withInstanceId(instanceId)
        .withBlockDeviceMappings(mappingSpecification);

ec2Client.modifyInstanceAttribute(request);
```